# Best way to use DNS and ephemeral OCI load balancer IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, dns, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We host a number of services in OCI using Kubernetes (OKE) Ingress on private subnets through OCI Load Balancers (K8s managed). We often need a DNS record to point to the load balancer's floating address.

Inevitably we tear down, or rebuild these ingresses when things change. Our problem is that we have no control over the private IPs that are assigned to these load balance instances, and thus have to re-point DNS each time which takes much longer than the Kubernetes deployment.

From what we can see OCI just picks the next free IP in the subnet range. I've search through the documentation, but I see no way of reserving internal IP addresses other than for Instance VNICs which don't apply here from what what I can see.

On premise we would reserve an IP in the private range to avoid this problem.

What's the best way to deal with this in OCI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the Private IP of the load balancer as static, however it is a feature supported by the REST API only.

you can refer this : https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/java-cloud/jscug/stop-start-and-restart-oracle-java-cloud-service-instance-and-individual-nodes.html#GUID-B663B1CE-1B99-40FF-9CDA-9BC76E43134E

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/java-cloud/jsrmr/op-paas-api-v1.1-instancemgmt-identitydomainid-services-jaas-instances-serviceid-hosts-command-post.html

Thank you,
Hemanth.

Comment: From what I can see the articles you refer to speak about stopping load balancer instances, not rebuilding them. What I need is a way to rebuild the Ingress / LB and maintain the IP that was assigned to the previous instance.

Answer (score 0):

We create 2 load balancers, 1st has the dns pointing to it and has a single backend set pointing to the 2nd load balancer that is integrated more with Kubernetes. Assuming in your scenario you'd only need to tear down and rebuild the 2nd load balancer you could then go and update the backend set of the 1st load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We considered this, and we may still implement it, it definitely works. My main reservation is that it uses more resources than we really need. But so far I think this is the best solution given the available tools.